# Change character jump height on one object

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am trying to make the character jump higher when jumping off of an object. I don't want the character to be launched immediately when colliding. I want the character to have a higher jump only when pressing the space bar on the object.

I already set the jumping z velocity to update in the character blueprint. The longer you press space, the higher the character jumps. I am not sure how I can change the jump z velocity while on the object, AND not affecting character's jump when off the object. I appreaciate any help you can provide. Thank you! [character blueprint for the jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imyqe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is to use the hit event from the collision (and cast to the specific object to see if its the right one).

1. If it's the case you adjust the jump height.
2. As soon if jump is called you adjust the jump height back to normal.
3. There is a small problem if you get off the object without ever
   jumping, so if the first hit event cast fails, also adjust the jump
   height back to normal.

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant version but let's begin somewhere ;)